# simple numeric token string 2 max 3 digits

Tags: 7, tokens

I need to generate numeric string and append it at the end of node url. Tried using some token random number options but the result is 10 digit number which is not neccessary for my purpose. Is there any other option? Node NID is not possible to use. Thank you

Comment: could you use the day of the month?

Comment: no it needs to be different in every node I create - max 20 nodes. I construct automatic url+title like this - referenced node + number string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$length = 3; // character length
$token = substr(drupal_hmac_base64($node->nid, drupal_get_private_key() . drupal_get_hash_salt()), 0, $length);
```

Comment: Hi, where to put this code? I can only use tokens available using UI.